# You don't have to be crazy to live here, but it helps

Tags: meaning

> The furniture of the den, a cement-floored room that ran the length of the house, consisted almost entirely of his carpentry (shelves, tables, stools, a ping-pong table) and Nacy's needlework (chintz slip covers that rejunvenated a decrepit couch, curtains, pillows bearing the legends: "Happy?" and "You don't have to be crazy to live here, but it helps").

I found this is the book ["In Cold Blood"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NGJubhmwqfoC&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=%22happy?+and+you+don%27t+have+to+be+crazy+to+live+here,+but+it+helps.%22&source=bl&ots=t-sxUlIDmh&sig=GkcD6VgV3DMGWy-EdZeeK-5102M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yHr8U5PlLMLy7AavjIGwAw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22happy%3F%20and%20you%20don%27t%20have%20to%20be%20crazy%20to%20live%20here%2C%20but%20it%20helps.%22&f=false) by Truman Capote

What does "You don't have to be crazy to live here, but it helps." mean?

Comment: They are two separate legends. "Happy?" means either "are you happy?" or "are you happy, now?"

Answer (score 2):

The presumption is that crazy people will do (or enjoy) things that “normal” people would not do or enjoy.

People will indeed say things like:

> You have to be crazy to eat that much pie!
>   You have to be crazy to like that kind of music!

Meaning that only crazy people would do or like those things.

Some things may not actually be *that* bad that *only* crazy people would do them, but they certainly would not be considered pleasant by “normal” people. So, figuratively, it would be more enjoyable (or simply easier to bear) for a crazy person than for a non-crazy person.

> You do not *have* to be crazy to work here, but it sure helps (to be crazy).

Means “normal” people work here too, but they suffer greatly. Being crazy reduces that suffering, and maybe crazy people even enjoy working here.

Answer (score 0):

It means to say that, being crazy does help you at times :)

Comment: Okay can the down voter kindly explain

Comment: You have neither given a rationale nor substantiated your answer (by reference to dictionary, phrase book, or other external authority). In other words: this answer, as it stands, reads like a personal opinion (which is already a no-no). At best, it seems like a mere rewording of the original question, but it doesn't even do *that* right (because "at times" is manifestly incorrect, & ruins the joke, which is clear if you read oerkelen's high quality answer). Usually I don't explain downvotes on manifestly poor answers that have had no work put into them, but since you asked, I hope this helps.